# Node.js Mongodb Intergration Issues; .save()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is an example site that I have created with a basic Node.js server. I am able to successfully post, create a user given the schema, and "save" to the database; however, saving does not return the user object and cannot be found in my actual database. The connection is also returned as successful.

main.js

```
const session = require('express-session');
const pug = require('pug');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const User = require('./schema.js');
const app = express();

var path = require('path');

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
var db;

client.connect((err, client) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else if (!err) {
    db = client.db('node');
    console.log('Connected to Mongodb');
    client.close()
  }
});

app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express)
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'styles')));
app.use(session({secret: 'testing',saveUninitialized: true,resave: true}));

//root directory get response
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('homepage', {
  title : 'Homepage',
  req : req
  });
});

//register directory get response
app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.render('register', {
  title : 'Register',
  req: req
  });
});

//profile directory get response
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  res.render('profile', {
    title: 'Profile',
    email: req.session.email,
    username: req.session.username,
    req: req
  });
});

//login directory get response
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', {
    title: 'Login',
    req: req
  })
})

//register directory post request
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  if(req.body.username && req.body.email && req.body.password){
    var user = User({
      email : req.body.email,
      username : req.body.username,
      password : req.body.password
    });
  console.log(user);
  user.save((err) => {
    user.markModified('password')
    console.log("Trying to save")
    console.log(user)
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var sess = req.session;
      sess.email = req.body.email;
      console.log("Saved")
      res.redirect('/profile')
      }
    });
  }
});

//login directory post request
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  if(req.body.username && req.body.password){
    var sess = req.session;
    sess.username = req.body.username;
    res.redirect('/profile')
  }
})

const server = app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

schema.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    unique: false,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(req, err, next) {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if(err){
      return next(err);
    }
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if(err){
        return next(err);
      }
      user.password = hash;
      console.log(hash);
      next()
    });
  });
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: ```const mongoose = require('mongoose')``` is present in schema.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using mongoose to create models and make db querys but not connecting to mongoose. Instead you are connecting to MongoDb native driver.

Replace this

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
var db;

    client.connect((err, client) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else if (!err) {
        db = client.db('node');
        console.log('Connected to Mongodb');
        client.close()
      }
    });
```

with

```
mongoose.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true});

mongoose.connection.on("open", function(ref) {
  console.log("Connected to mongo server.");
});

mongoose.connection.on("error", function(err) {
  console.log("Could not connect to mongo server!");
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Ah, thank you; however, the User object created from the POST is saved as indexes rather than an Object under mongo. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `var user = new User({ ... });` instead of this `var user = User({ ... });`. Notice the `new` keyword.